# Plot hole in Watch_Dogs - did I miss something? (Possible Spoilers)

Tags: watch-dogs

I'm enjoying Watch_Dogs and the main story picked up a bit after the first few missions.

Anyway, I'm now in Act IV and I can't help wondering if I missed something in a previous act.

> Early on in the game, the main antagonist, *Damien*, kidnaps Aidan's sister.  Aidan spends most of the rest of the game brutally slaughtering various gang members in order to get her back.  Not only that, he traces phone-calls and hunts people down via the ctOS network on several occasions throughout the main campaign and in various side missions.

Did I miss something here?  Why doesn't Aidan simply

> Trace Damien's calls in the same way and hunt down the location he's holding his sister?  He handled an entire apartment block full of Iraq's goons with relative ease and from what I can gather, Damien does not have anywhere near as many resources as Iraq (at least in the early game).

Does this get explained anywhere, or are we left to simply make assumptions that, for example

> Aidan is worried if he makes a direct attack, Damien will simply kill his sister?

If that's the case, why, at the beginning of Act IV, does Aidan

> Call Damien's bluff by telling him to kill his sister?  Surely if he thought Damien was bluffing, he would have made a positive move against Damien to retrieve her, rather than the passive move he made.

Comment: Your last question is because he has something on him. It is a kind of mutual assured destruction kinda thing.

Comment: Aiden has monologues for the entire game debating whether he should go after Damien or not.  This isn't a plot hole, it's just you saying you would have done things differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all

> Aiden could have killed Damian when he told him he had kidnapped his sister, but that would not help him to reveal her location. Damian also would probably have a failsafe in place (like "If you don't hear from me every hour, kill the girl).

On the other hand, Damian would not be so stupid

> to call him from the place where he kept his sister, as he probably knows what Aiden is capable of. So he only made his move once he also had some leverage on Damian. Damian could not kill his sister, because then he would never get the data and Blume would kill him, because he had no leverage on them.

So in short, Aiden did the only thing possible to him.

Edit: As Philipp pointed out, in the end

> Aiden finds the location of his sister trough a mistake made by Damian. This also shows that it was not possible for Aiden to find out the location of his sister before that point.

Comment: You might want to add that Aidan does in the end find his sisters location because of a mistake Damien makes.

Comment: Funny, I played it only a few days ago but can not remember for the love of my life what that mistake was...

Comment: During one of the phonecalls with Nicole, Aidan hears a voice in the background. Aidan then gives a recording of that phonecall to T-Bone who analyzes it and finds her location.

Comment: I actually got the distinct impression that for most of the game Aiden didn't consider Damien a real threat, so he left his sister in the background because Damien needed him too much (plus the fact that Damien's intel was actually solid which made Aiden interested in following it up on his own anyway).

Comment: Doesn't Aiden get the hacks that give him access to all of cTos from Damien at the start? I would assume from that that Damien was a better hacker then Aiden, and that Aiden would not immediately have the ability to track Damien down through hacking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Damien was able to mask his location, so the calls couldn't simply be traced.  The only reason that Aiden got a lead on his sister's location is because he overheard a distinct sound in the background, which he was then able to determine the source of.